# Explanation of this CSS code

Tags: html, css

I need to know what exactly this code does.. or how this can be used..Actually I used this to repeat the image as a background for the menu .. Need explanation for this..

```
url("images/home_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent
```

Comment: Please replace in the title HTML with CSS, and add a CSS tag :)

Answer (score 6):

It's shorthand notation for the `background` CSS property. Shorthand is a bad idea for exactly this reason: It's hard to figure out what is what.

The long version looks like this:

```
background-image: url("images/home_bg.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-x;                  /* Repeat image horizontally */
background-attachment: scroll;                /* Whether image is fixed 
                                                 or scrolls with page */
background-position: 0 0;                     /* x position, y position */
background-color: transparent;
```

[Docs on the background properties](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Answer (score 0):

That's not HTML, it's [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/). It's saying to use the given image as the background, repeat it horizontally but not vertically, start at 0,0, and make it transparent (this last refers to the background *color*, rather than the image). More about [CSS backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html) on the W3C website.

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on those properties, and more, at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp.